# Is Confluent killing the interceptors with it last release 5.3.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-control-center

As we can see in the last Confluent 5.3.0 release documentation:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/monitoring.html

The only dashboard in order to monitorize the interceptors is marked as deprecated.

Is now Confluent going to stop using the interceptors?

Comment: Deprecated sometimes means there's a replacement, not permanently removed. If you're paying for Confluent Enterprise, better to ask your sales reps or open a Support ticket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Data Streams page in the new Consumption monitoring view has been redesigned, which does require the interceptors. 
We’re always interested in feedback on this feature, as we are continuing to improve end-to-end streams monitoring in Control Center. DM me on http://cnfl.io/slack if you've got any feedback to share.